# How to open a .DBF file with a .DAT extension

Tags: c#-4.0, odbc, dbase

I need to open a dbase III file in C#. The sticking point is that the file has a .dat extension not a .dbf. I have tried both OleDB and Odbc and both require that the file has a .dbf extension.

Renaming the file is not an option. These come from a customer as part of a GIS TAB file set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know that the the OleDB connection can point to a "path" where the data resides... However, I think you can explicitly qualify the file name to include the .dat such as

```
select * from YourTable.DAT where SomeCondition;
```

your typical query would have been

```
select * from YourTable where SomeCondition;
```

and the OleDB provider would IMPLY a ".dbf" extension.  However, since you are explicitly qualifying as .DAT, it should find it for you.  Additionally, via OleDB, you can actually query from sub-folders from a common root (just FYI).

Comment: Tried this. Work only if .DBF file also present. This suggests extension is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If the file resides on writable NTFS volume you could establish hard link to this file: [Fsutil: hardlink](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true)